# How to aumotmate VBA in Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following macro written down In Excel.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:E2").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A3:E3").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Now the A2:E2 range needs to be repeated from A2:E2 until A30:E30. And the C2 in the second line should be D2, E2 ,F2 and so on for each increment.

How can this existing code be modified to achieve the result I need as mentioned above?

Thanks in advance for your help.

With regards,
Manus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simply:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:E30").Copy
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

   Application.CutCopyMode=false
End Sub
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
For I = 0 To 29

    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Range(Range("A2").Offset(I, 0), Range("A2").Offset(I, 4)).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("C2").Offset(0, I).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Taosique. i used simoco's answer but I will also test this one out and see if it satisfies the same requirement.